# trigger not inserting records

Tags: trigger

I have two object MP_Claims__c(custom object) and Case, having lookup relationship from MP_Claims__c to Case and Case to MP_Claims__c. Trying to insert(create a case) a record after insert/create MP_Claim record. And the criteria is a picklist field 'Claim Reason' in MP_Claims__c should have the value 'Recovery'. Unable to find any debuglogs also here, what's the mistake I am doing?.

```
trigger New_Case_V1 on MPClans__c(after insert)
{
try{
    List<Case> lstcs = new List<Case>();

//Loop for each new Recovery
    for(MPClans__c mpclns: Trigger.new)
    {
     if((mpclns.Reason__c == 'Recovery ') 
         && (mpclns.Case__c == False) )
      {
        Case cs = new Case();
   //Query a queue for it's Label which is A queue sobject.     
       QueueSObject QueueID = [Select Queue.Id, Queue.Name, Queue.Type from QueueSObject WHERE Queue.Type ='Queue' AND Queue.Name = 'Market_team' Limit 1];       
          cs.MPClans__c = mpclns.Id;
     //     cs.Account = mpcl.Account;    
          cs.Status = 'New';           
          cs.OwnerId = QueueID.Queue.Id;                   

        lstcs.add(cs);
          system.debug('---------insert'+lstcs);
      }     

    }
insert lstcs;

}catch(Exception ex){
system.debug('An exception occured in trigger named "New_Case_V1" and the exception is::'+ex);
}


}
```

Comment: You should remove that exception handler, which is likely swallowing and hiding an exception. Swallowing exceptions is very bad practice. Once you do, any error will immediately be surfaced to you.

Comment: Why do you have a trailing space in `'CC Chargeback Recovery '`?  If that space isn't in the actual field value, the record will be skipped.

Comment: @DavidCheng Further, fields *cannot* store leading or trailing whitespace. It will always be trimmed. Therefore, that condition can never be true.

Comment: Thank you!! @David Cheng and sfdcfox 'CC Chargeback Recovery' is the culprit here.